# Review - are section filters applied on review main page?

Tags: feature-request, review

The review sections (suggested edits, first posts, reopen votes, etc.) have a very nice feature allowing users to define their own filters per review section.

Are those filters applied on the review main page, too?

I haven't been able to find out whether they are (*but deleted faster than I could click section links*) or not.

In case they are ***not*** applied:

I think it would be helpful for the community, if the review main page also would take those section filters into account (*if any are set by the user*).

It's about all the sections except for the big close vote section with 100k+ items around.

If the main page shows something like 12 Suggested Edits and 24 First Posts, but selecting them mostly results in empty pages with the message

> There are no items for you to review, matching the filter *[x][y]*

then this is not very effective. It feels like a waste of time and you maybe get annoyed, frustrated, [insert your reasons here].

Personally I wouldn't even need the exact numbers matching my filters. Just any kind of indicator that a specific section really *does* contain items matching my filter.

What do you think?